# MVC - Multiple Databases(Oracle, SQL)

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture

Is it bad practice to include two db entities in a single controller. I have to update multiple databases with information from each other. One Oracle and the other SQL Server.

Seems like Code First will not work with Oracle(DEVart state that they can, costly!!). Other way was to create database first with model for both databases and then include them in the same controller. Just want some opinions on the subject. I have the code working just wondering about performance etc....

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have two databases?  And of different flavours to boot?  Please explain your scenario in more depth.